# Removing string outside of JSON

Tags: c#, json

Usually JSON string comes wrapped in a bracket like the following--

```
{
    "Result":"1",
    "ErrorText":"",
    "Item":[{
        "@value":"1",
        "Postcode":"B6 4AA",
        "PostcodeFrom":"",
        "Key":"B6 4AA1001",
        "List":"B6 4AA Royal Mail, Birmingham Mail Centre, St. Stephens Street, BIRMINGHAM", "CountryISO":"GBR"
    }]
}
```

But for some strange reason the JSON I'm getting from [AFD](http://www.afd.co.uk/support/manuals/sdk/json-jsonp-manual/) services is following format

```
JSON({
        "Result":"1",
        "ErrorText":"",
        "Item":[{
            "@value":"1",
            "Postcode":"B6 4AA",
            "PostcodeFrom":"",
            "Key":"B6 4AA1001",
            "List":"B6 4AA Royal Mail, Birmingham Mail Centre, St. Stephens Street, BIRMINGHAM", "CountryISO":"GBR"
        }]
    })
```

My plan is to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and deserialize the JSON string, but pasting the code ABOVE the one with JSON({}) is giving me error. So I guess I have to get rid of string `JSON` somehow before I can deserialize.

Question is HOW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the result in JSONP format instead of JSON. Use the `Format=JSON` parameter to get JSON instead.

Comment: Just figure it out! Lol you beat me to it! But thank you sir!